# Where does the movie downloaded from "Play Movies & TV" get stored in external SD card?

Tags: sd-card, google-play-movies

I recently bought and downloaded a movie from "Play Movies & TV" application. It is not automatically detected by any other video player. So, where does the movie downloaded from "Play Movies & TV" get stored in external SD card?

Comment: Mine were never detected by VLC either. It looks like the files were broken up into pieces but there is no single movie file.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought and downloaded the 90 minute Google "AlphaGo" documentary movie in HD. It was about 2 GB in size.

It was saved on the SD card in this folder (I obscured the exact name with *):

> Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files/Movies/YXJh******NvbQ/ylEP****BE/

In that folder were 156 files with names like this made-up format:

> 0.163253726153.23764387642386.v3.exo

Each *.v3.exo file was about 2-25 MB in size. There was also a single file called

> cached_content_index.exi

So I imagine the download was made into smaller chunks.

The "*.v3.exo" format is a YouTube format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the files downloaded from the Google Play Movies & TV goes over to the internal storage of the device you can find it over `sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files/Movies`,

The files will be in the `.wvm` format like `abc.wvm`.

Comment: That directory is empty :(

Comment: @thefourtheye It should be `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files/Movies/****.wvm` for sure, but use a file explorer and search for `.wvm` files and it might shed more light on it. Make sure you can see hidden files also. However, you can set it external storage in the Play Movies settings if you have an EXT SD card so if you have done that it'll be on the EXT SD.

Comment: I don't get that, I go into the same folder, but see a bunch of extra files and no .wvm files... Please help! :)